# Insufficient Hexadecimal Digits Regex Exception?

Tags: c#, regex, unicode

I am formulating a regex where it would match with all letters (including chinese) and some chosen punctuations (also including chinese).

Here's my regex

```
"^[\p{L}\x{FF01}-\x{FF1E}\x{3008}-\x{30A9}0-9\s@#$^&*()+=,.?`~_:;|""-{}[]+$"
```

It throws an exception of insufficient hexadecimal digits. Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with it? I tried some regex testers online and it works there.

Im using the Regex class of c# to parse it

Comment: *tell me what's wrong with it?* Not without samples of the text you're using it on that are throwing the exception. There's nothing wrong with the regex itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference):

> `\x nn`   Uses hexadecimal representation to specify a character (nn consists of exactly two digits).

I think what you want is `\u`:

> `\u nnnn` Matches a Unicode character by using hexadecimal representation (exactly four digits, as represented by nnnn).

Try this:

```
@"^[\p{L}\uFF01-\uFF1E\u3008-\u30A90-9\s@#$^&*()+=,.?`~_:;|""-{}[]+$"
```